# How to see the commits from one branch to another

Tags: git

I used to do this with a simple command but I have forgotten how to do it and cannot find it

How can I see the commits (like a log) that separate one branch from another?

Comment: Just for background, are you using the Git Bash directly, a Git plugin, an IDE, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Ooops I found this already, and it was very simple

```
git log <options> <first branch> <second branch>
```

recommended is options `--oneline`

```
git log --oneline --graph <first branch> <second branch>
```